# Отправка email через InlineKeyboardButton

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть бот, который выдаёт контакты человека из бд через `InlineKeyboardButton`. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с email, открывалась почтовая программа для отправки письма?

`url='mailto:some@mail.com'` подставляет `http://.`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать модуль **webbrowser** **python**, чтобы открыть ссылку **mailto**.

Это откроет почтовый клиент по умолчанию на устройстве пользователя с указанным адресом электронной почты в поле «Кому», что позволит им составить и отправить электронное письмо.

Вы можете использовать этот код внутри функции обратного вызова вашего **InlineKeyboardButton** в боте **Telegram**.

```
import webbrowser
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton

def email_callback(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    email = "some@mail.com"
    url = f'mailto:{email}'
    webbrowser.open(url)
    query.answer("Email client opened.")

keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Email", callback_data='email', callback=email_callback)]]
```

Это откроет почтовую программу с адресом электронной почты в качестве получателя при нажатии кнопки.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но в таком виде почтовик открывается на компе (судя по всему на сервере, а не на клиенте).